# Popup window django after form submission

Tags: javascript, python, django

How do I have a popup box appear after someone has submitted a form?  For example after submitting a form, I want a popup box to appear saying "Successfully submitted".  The way I have the view now is that it just redirects to a page saying "Successfully submitted".  Instead of this I want a popup window to appear with the form in the background.

```
def addDog(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = DogForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      post = form.save(commit=False)
      post.save()
      return HttpResponse("Successfully submitted")
    else:
      print("Unable to save. Form is not valid")
      print(form.errors)
  else:
    form = DogForm()
  return render(request, "app/addDog.html", {"form":form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this in JavaScript. At a high level, make an AJAX POST request to the same endpoint that you had been. Upon success, use `window.alert("Successfully submitted!")`.

If this is the extent of your JS on your site, then jQuery is a bit overkill, but it is easiest to give an example using jQuery:

```
$("#submit-button").on("click", function() {
    $.post("http://some/endpoint/here", $("#my-form").serialize())
        .done(function() { window.alert("Successfully submitted!"); })
        .fail(function() { window.alert("Submission failed!"); });
});
```

The functions used in this are: [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) [$().on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [$().serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

This can be implemented without much issue in vanilla JavaScript, but it is more verbose so I'm not going to do it in this example.

Comment: This doesn't seem to show the error messages when a field is entered incorrectly.  When I submit the form it should tell me I'm missing a field, but it still submits it (even though it is not accepted in by the database).

Comment: You either have to do validation in JS or do validation in Django and then parse the response in JS. If you do it like this you don't get the Django error messages for free. It will take extra work (and likely a lot of it). I'd recommend looking at `django-ajax`. Maybe that'll make things easier

Answer (score -1):

You need to add Javascript on the form submission event in the template

```
<form method="post" id="DogForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}     

    </table>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>

  </form>
<script>
$("#DogForm").on('submit', function(event) {
      alert("New Dog Added");
</script>
```

Comment: Need to close on function